# load balancer won't remove itself from dns

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I switched to autoscaling today and I created a new load balancer to practice with.  Once I got everything configured the way I liked it, I changed the A record to point to the new load balancer alias.

Then the weirdness begins...

My traffic has now split between the two load balancers.

Here's some stuff that may help:

```
elb-describe-lbs
...snip
LOAD_BALANCER  lb-app           lb-app-2007138663.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com          2012-12-01T04:36:44.480Z  internet-facing
LOAD_BALANCER  app-lb-west      app-lb-west-650828891.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com      2013-06-28T01:34:26.810Z  internet-facing
```

I added `app-lb-west` and then switched the alis from `lb-app` to `app-lb-west`.  Now I'm getting 1/2 the traffic spread between the two lbs.

I could use some help, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I nslookup your domain I get app-lb-west-650828891.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com:

DNS server handling your query: localhost

DNS server's address:  127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:

Name:  codepen.io

Address: 54.245.121.59

It is possible that the DNS change just needed a little time to propagate.

Comment: Thanks...

so should I just leave this alone for a few hours and see if the traffic drops off?

Also, what flags did you give to nslookup?  I'd like to be able to do this myself.

Comment: I just used an external service http://www.kloth.net/services/nslookup.php, yeah I would just give it a bit of time, shouldn't take hours but with DNS caching you can't really be sure it wont.

Comment: i need some sleep.  I only changed *.codepen.io and not .codepen.io in route53.  Thanks for your help.